# Center align text in ASP.net menu

Tags: asp.net, css

New to asp.net and I am trying to center the hover portion of my menu control but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
    <aside>
        <nav>
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                RenderingMode="Table" backcolor="#CB4154" ForeColor="white" Font-Bold="True" >
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="8px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticMenuStyle height="25px" Width="800px" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle HorizontalPadding="8px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticHoverStyle Font-Bold="True" height="75%" width="50%" backcolor="#00B7EB" ForeColor="White" CssClass="StaticHoverStyle"/>
        </asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
        </nav>
    </aside>
```

And the CSS:

```
#Menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.StaticHoverStyle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any input on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

make it `absolute` and add `right` and `left` tags

> ```
> #Menu {
> position:absolute;
> text-align: center;
> margin-right:auto;
> margin-left: auto;
> right:0px;
> left:0px; }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> .StaticHoverStyle {
>     text-align: center;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't affect the hover part, normally its centered but when I hover over it, the text goes to left align. Not sure if I was clear in my question, but that is the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

i just had a quick look at mine (been a while) and it looks like i put text-align in a wrapping div. what happens it you move your text-align to the nav element? (move the data source out, for clarity.)

Comment: on hover it looks like the width is being cut in half. is that not drastically affecting something?

Comment: Thank you wazz, something SOOO simple could cause such an annoying issue. That has fixed it.